# Finding and counting number of checked boxes using JQuery

Tags: jquery, html

I have one form on a page and within that form there will be a check box for every row in the table. I need to count the number of rows that have a checked row, but I am having trouble even selecting that from jQuery.

Here is what my code looks like for a checkbox:

```
<input type="checkbox" id="onHomePage_56" name="onHomePage" 
    value="56" checked="checked">
```

An unchecked box doesn't have checked="checked".

Comment: What have you tried?  Did you try checking the docs?  http://api.jquery.com/category/selectors/

Comment: Ahh was just missing the colon between input and checked

Answer (score 7, accepted):

```
var q = $('form#id-of-form').find('input:checked').length;
```

http://api.jquery.com/checked-selector/

If there are checkboxes in the form you don't want counted, then add a class to the ones you *do* want counted and select those instead:

```
var q = $('form#id-of-form').find('input.count-these:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 2):

jQuery provides special selectors for this:

```
$('input:checked').length
```

More specifically:

```
var num = $('#myform input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

I added the jQuery `:checkbox` selector because `:checked` applies to radio buttons as well.  Technically, `:checkbox` is slower than `[type=checkbox]` in modern browsers, but they do the same thing:

```
var num = $('#myform input[type=checkbox]:checked').length;
```

Answer (score 1):

You could try this:

```
$('#form input:checkbox:checked').length;
```

Answer (score -1):

```
$('#myForm table tr td input:checked')​.size();​
```

[**DEMO.**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TT8zh/1/)

**Update:** Better to filter `type` because you could have checked radio buttons too

```
$('#myForm table tr td input[type="checkbox"]:checked').size();
```

[**Demo with checked radio buttons**](http://jsfiddle.net/heera/TT8zh/2/)